# How to parse a htm file using Beautiful soup

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse a htm local file using BeautifulSoup.

.htm is filetype.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
with open('locfile.htm') as fp:
   soup = BeautifulSoup(fp, "html5lib")
print(soup)
```

Trying the three different parsers, but the same result is obtained. 
Example for the  html5lib

```
<html><body><p>t a b l e   i d = " T a b l a D a t a "   c l a s s = " T a b l a    w i d t h = " 9 0 %  &gt; 
 t r &gt;....

.....
```

and so on. I think that "&gt" is  but is transformed to those string.

Similar results are obtained using `html.parser` and `html5llib`

How can I do to mantain the tags into the body?

Could it be a wrong parsing operation?

```
soup.contents
[<html><head></head><body>&lt;table id=........
..................
</body></html>
```

but the inner tags have been missing, or transformed into html escape characters

How do I maintain the tags?

Comment: We can't help you with a code problem unless you post the code you have written. You're asking us to imagine what you have written and then guess why it doesn't work as you expect.

Comment: Does the file look ok if viewed in a text editor? Are you able to post a link to the file?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I have found the sollution.

The problem was the encoding of the original file :

```
with open('locfile.htm',encoding="utf-16LE") as fp:
```